# Populate tableview with multilevel nested JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsjsonserialization

I have a requirement to populate tableview with multilevel nested json.

So based on selection of categoryName, a subcategory populates and previous section/row collapses and title is updated with the selection and when i select a subcategory, another subcategory populates with expand/collapse and this goes to multilevel. I am clueless and need insights.

Comment: I have tried creating a model class for keeping the json data. I was able to parse it to some extent but have no clue on how to keep corresponding subcategories based on categories selection.

Comment: Can anyone share his/her email id, so i can share the complete requirement flow and what i have done till now?

Comment: looks like we've same problem, is your case here solved yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using two ways:

**First:**

You need to right the logic to make `UITableView` collapsable using two array like: FullTableViewData array and CurrentContentShowingArray.

**Second:**

You can use ThirdParty classes.

[RRNCollapsableSectionTableViewSwift](https://github.com/rob-nash/CollapsableTable)

Comment: Could you please try... i have updated link in my answer